# Prettier extension is not working in vs code Require config set to true

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, prettier

Prettier extension is not working I set it by default and format on save he give me an error: "Require config set to true and no config present. Skipping file."

Answer (score 5):

[image]

`ctrl + ,` in vscode,then paste it `Prettier: Require Config` and unchecked the option.

Answer (score 2):

That disables the warning without solving the problem.

You're missing a Prettier configuration file.

There are a lot of ways to install one, but the simplest way is described in the [Prettier Documentation](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html), which suggests creating a file at root called `.prettierrc.js` with the following module inside:

```
module.exports = {
  trailingComma: "es5",
  tabWidth: 4,
  semi: false,
  singleQuote: true,
};
```

There are a LOT more options to configure, and a Google search will show you existing templates like [the one used by AirBnB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettier-airbnb-config).

Comment: Also check if you have prettier config defined in the package.json. I downloaded a boilerplate that had such config and somewhat, got the same error message while my prettier config file was not taken into account.